# Setting ng-controller dynamically from a variable value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-controller

I am developing an application using angularJs and nodejs. Am struck at setting the name of the controller to the value of a variable from main controller. To explain it better, my index.html looks like this :

```
        <tbody ng-repeat="group in groups">

        <tr ng-repeat="member in group.members" >
            <td rowspan="{{group.members.length}}" ng-hide="$index>=0">
            </td>

            <td>{{member.taskName}}</td>
            <td><div class={{group.colorMe[0]}}>{{member.env}}</div>
                <button class="btn btn-info" ng-controller="member.taskName" ng-click="test( member.taskName , 'env', group.colorMe[0])">Sanity</button>
            </td>
```

And my main Controller looks like this where the groups are defined as this :

```
  var tasks =['task1','task2','task3','task4','task5'];

      for(i=0;i<tasks.length;i++)

    {

    var group = {
                  "id" : i+1,
                  "members" : [{
                      "taskName":tasks[i].toUpperCase(),
                      "env1":versionMap["env1"+tasks[i]],
                      "env2":versionMap["env2"+tasks[i]],
                      "env3":versionMap["env3"+tasks[i]]

                  }]
                };
              $scope.groups.push(group);
              }
```

Now when i click the button , I should be direcrted to a particular controller and this controller name needs to be set dynamically to member.taskName . Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Have you got the solution ?

Comment: @NareshKumar Trying the solution provided by Leguest. Any suggestions?

Comment: actually i am curious to know the answer to it @NagireddyHanisha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some extra logic to your service. So it will require new dependencies such as: `$controller`, `$compile`, `$root$scope` or `$scope`. And optional one `$templateCache`. Templates are optional as well.

**DEMO** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kf5gad4c/1/)

Dynamic controller service:

```
var controllerTemplate = $templateCache.get(params.templateUrl); // getting inline template string

var templateScope = $rootScope.$new(true); // creating new scope for future controlelr
var templateCtrl = $controller(dynamicControllerName, { // creating controller
     $scope: templateScope // locals stuff that inject in controller           
});

var dynamicControllerElement = angular.element(controllerTemplate); // wrapping template into element

dynamicControllerElement.children().data('$ngControllerController', templateCtrl); // inject controller into element

var compiled = $compile(dynamicControllerElement)(templateScope); // compile all together

$('.container').html(compiled); // putting compiled into DOM (jQuery example)
```

More specific code for you:

**Directive**

```
 app.directive('dynamicControllerButton', function(dynamicControllerService){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
         controllerName: '='
      },
      template: '<button class="btn btn-info">Sanity</button>', //added this comma
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

           dynamicControllerService.createController(scope.controllerName, elem); // we passing also element;

    }

  }

})
```

**Service**

```
app.service('dynamicControllerService', function($rootScope, $controller, $compile){

     this.createController = function(dynamicControllerName, element) {

    // all that stuff in example above

      element.html(compiled); // adding compiled controller in element example ;

     }

})
```

**HTML**

```
    <tr ng-repeat="member in group.members" >
        <td rowspan="{{group.members.length}}" ng-hide="$index>=0">
        </td>

        <td>{{member.serviceName}}</td>
        <td><div class={{group.colorMe[0]}}>{{member.env}}</div>
            <dynamic-controller-button>  data-controller-name="dynamic_set_controller" ng-click="test( member.serviceName , 'env', group.colorMe[0])"></dynamic-controller-button>
        </td>
```

I hope it will help

Comment: What is a controller service? Where do I need to plug in that code?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Will try this out. :)

Comment: I could not follow how the value of the controller-name is being set and also, $controller, $compile, $root$scope or $scope, $templateCache that you suggested, should all 5 of these be in the main controller or in my nested controller that I am setting?

Comment: No they being set only in `dynamicControllerService `.  `controller-name` passed into directive `dynamicControllerButton `, and then passed to service method `createController`

Comment: Thanks again. So, since I needed controoler-name as taskName(I updated the question for better understanding of others), in my case it should be 
data-controller-name="member.serviceName" (member.taskName in updated question). Also, just to update you about the progress, I have incorporated your answer in the code, 
and my getting an error saying var controllerTemplate = $templateCache.get(params.templateUrl); trying to figure out this, it says params not defined.

Comment: Yes, you are right. As I said tempates are optional, so you could do something like `var controllerTemplate = '<button>Sanity</button>'. And don't even use `$tempalteCache` at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142892/discussion-between-nagireddy-hanisha-and-leguest).