# modal in modal or a div to "hide and show" in a modal angular js 1 and html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i have my modal already wish enable me to add informations about "thing1" but in same modal i have to add specific informations relieted to that "thing1" ! those informations must appear in the modal when i clik on add more specific informations ..it must appears as an other modal (modal in modal) i searched much and i dnt know if using angular js & html i can do this ! otherwise i tried to put in modal a part which "shows" and "hides" up to my needs if i click or not . like this : https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_events_hide
but this doesn't wrk in a modal! who can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `angular material` https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog

With this props

```
 preserveScope: true,
 autoWrap: true,
 skipHide: true,
```

Here is [Example](https://codepad.co/snippet/mYaUNz7x), or could try to create own service

One of my [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43672698/setting-ng-controller-dynamically-from-a-variable-value/43672818#43672818) is similar about creating dialogs